# robot with lost sensor measurements

Tags: bluetooth, localization, bluetooth-lowenergy, delay, packet-loss

I am trying to implement a localization algorithm for 4 robots on a Raspberry, the robots move too fast and send sensor measurements via Bluetooth low energy to the Raspberry but sometimes the packets arrive late or get lost so they don't reflect the actual state of the robots .

How can I deal with that?

Comment: BLE is not a good choice for a fast moving robot. You need a real time protocol.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot change it or build a real-time protocol on it, I want to know if there is a localization algorithm (a Bayes filter for example) that can deal with delayed and lost measurements.

Answer (score 0):

How often are you sending sensor measurements? In addition, if you're worried about lost packets, you could try using Indicate as that ensures that the receiver has read the message.